# Printing all defined variables and values

Tags: php

```
<?php echo ‘<pre>’; print_r(get_defined_vars()); echo ‘</pre>’; ?>
```

This is just giving me the arrays for defined variables but not priniting out any variables. How can I print values too?

Also what function can I use to output all the defined variables in this format:

> Variable name | Variable Type [int, array, string, bool] | Variable defined on line | Variable defined in script | Variable used times | Variable Value

Comment: `get_defined_vars` prints out defined variables *and values* quite fine. If you do not like the `print_r` format, then iterate over the result array and print them out in your desired format. Infos like `Variable defined on line | Variable defined in script | Variable used times` are not available in PHP.

Comment: print_r is not printing out the all data

Comment: it's better to use `get_defined_vars` with `var_dump` here is an example https://stackhowto.com/how-to-print-all-defined-variables-and-values-in-php/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

The php documentation should help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own debug output, by iterating through the array of returned to display gettype, value and name. However, the where it was defined, how much its been used, you cant do. PHP doesnt work that way