# Is there a way to print list of variables what are defined in included file in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, include

```
<?php
// this is test.php

$variable1 = "test1";
$variable2 = "test2";
?>
```

Is it possible to print list of these variable names in "index.php" ?

```
<?php
// this is index.php

$variable3 = "test3";
$variable4 = "test4";

include("test.php");

/* Here print names of variables from "test.php" somehow...? 
(Only "$variable1", "$variable2")
*/
?>
```

Comment: `get_defined_vars()` MAY help: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing all defined variables and values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529827/printing-all-defined-variables-and-values)

Answer (score 0):

try on index.php

```
<?php

$variable3 = "test3";
$variable4 = "test4";

include("test.php");
echo $variable1;
echo $variable2;
?>
```

Comment: Yes, of course, but I meant how to print the names of variables: "$variable1", "$variable2"

Comment: Sry my english, the better question would be; How to print the NAMES OF VARIABLES from included file in PHP?